# Problem when calling an onclick on canvas elements (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't want to abuse you so I'm asking for you just try to help me if you really like helping, haha.

I'm trying to make an inventory system (like RPG inventory) and I got stuck for around 4 hours just trying to make onclick event works for deleting object from a list.

I'm sending you my git repo with the code and... I know it might be boring, but if you want to invest some time trying to help me with that problem and even evaluating my code (cause I just started with Unity, and I'm learning it alone, so my code probably isn't great) I'll be thankfull.

https://github.com/alanduartes/inventory-system-unity

Thank you people, hope someone get excited to see that.

Comment: I think you should share your relevant code rather than the whole repository for you to get help faster and better.

Comment: agreed you are asking too much for someone to clone your repo, post the script you are having troubles with, what you have tried and what error messages if any you are getting